Как задать директорию в проекте
Хочу в переменную задать путь, чтобы всегда была выбрана конкретная папка, где находится проект, даже когда я перетаскиваю проект в другую папку
import os
directory = r'currentDirectory'

как это реализовать

Можешь полностью путь к файлу указать, типа вот так dir = "C:\Users\User\your_folder", или использовать переменную PATH, хотя 1 вариант более удобный

ну, то есть , почитать документацию по модулю os лень?  os.getcwd().

@Nazar каким образом ваш "первый вариант" удобнее, если автор вопроса прямо пишет, что должна быть выбрана папка с проектом даже после перемещения этой папки?

@strawdog я не правильно тогда вопрос понял, можешь забыть что я говорил

В переменной __file__ записан путь к текущему py файлу. Можно убрать из него имя файла, тогда получите путь к директории, где этот файл лежит. Проще всего это сделать через модуль pathlib:
from pathlib import Path

project_directory = Path(__file__).parent

Дальше работать как с объектом Path, например добавить имя файла можно так: project_directory / "some_file.txt".
Или преобразовать путь в строку, и работать с путем в виде строки:
str(project_directory) + "/some_file.txt"
